# Electron propagator in a strong background B field

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, polarization

Near a magnetar with $B>B_\rm{QED}$, the strong B field will suppress the Compton scattering cross section of photons with a specific polarization (E-mode). Some references I know deal this problem using time-dependent perturbation in quantum mechanics.

My question is there an intuitive way in QED to see how this takes place and why polarization is important in this case. The electron propagator will be modified. How can we include the background field in the filed theory calculation and derive it?